Hearing the cry of a baby - abandoning practice for action?
In the Jewish tradition of Hassidut Chabad, there's a well-known story about the need to be ready to abandon practice towards enlightenment in favor of compassionate action which is the manifestation of enlightenment itself.
Here's the story (source):

The Alter Rebbe shared his house with his oldest married son, Rabbi Dov Ber (who later succeeded him as the Mitteler Rebbe). Rabbi Dov Ber was known for his unusual power of concentration. Once, when Rabbi Dov Ber was engrossed in learning, his baby, sleeping in its cradle nearby, fell out and began to cry. The infant’s father did not hear the baby’s cries. But the infant’s grandfather, the Alter Rebbe, also engrossed in his studies in his room on the upper floor at the time, most certainly did. He interrupted his studies, went downstairs, picked the baby up, soothed it and replaced it in its cradle. Through all this Rabbi Dov Ber remained quite oblivious.
Subsequently, the Alter Rebbe admonished his son: “No matter how engrossed one may be in the loftiest occupation, one must never remain insensitive to the cry of a child.”

Is there a similar story in the Buddhism tradition, with a similar message?

“As I understand the Dhamma taught by the Blessed One, it’s not easy, living at home, to practice the holy life totally perfect, totally pure, a polished shell." - MN 82. There is a reason for everything....when we pick up one end of a stick; we pick up the other. This is why accomplished meditators lived in seclusion and only re-engage society after securing a certain level of achievement.

Compassionate Buddha not only listened to child’s cry but also to the cries of poor, downtrodden, rich, famous etc. (practically everyone!!)
Here is an interesting story:
When seven year old Rahula was ordained by Buddha, the father of Sidhartha, a king, was grieved. The king had lost Siddhartha and Nanda, his sons, and Devdatta, his nephew. But now that his grandson had been taken from him, he went to Blessed One and spoke to him. And then Blessed One promised that from that time forward he would not ordain any minor without the consent of his parents or guardians.
Moral of the story: Feel the genuine pain of others and take steps to not to make the baby cry again.

I wondered what would the fate of Ven. Rahula be if he'd remained in the Sakyan clan and became the king after his grandfather.

Wouldn't Buddha already know not to do that? Doesn't that contradict his alleged omniscience?

The following story comes in the Saṅgāmaji Sutta (Udana 1.8).
It is about a monk by the name of Sanghamaji, who, when seated under a tree, was visited by his former wife, carrying their infant son. She tried several times to get his attention, and having failed, left the son at his feet and went a short distance away, to observe his reaction. The monk neither reacted, nor said anything to the woman or her child. She then took back the child and left the scene, while lamenting about her former husband's lack of feelings for them, saying "the monk doesn't even care about his son."
The Buddha, who witnessed this supernaturally, praised the monk, saying (I paraphrase here) that he showed equanimity and is free from attachment, and is therefore a brahman.
I asked a question about this here: "The monk who ignored his visiting wife and infant son".

OP: Is there a similar story in the Buddhism tradition, with a similar message?

It's a similar story with an opposite or perhaps different message.
The monk's former wife tried unsuccessfully to use their infant son to emotionally overwhelm, entice and lastly blackmail the former monk back to the worldly life.
This is different from the story of Rabbi Dov Ber, who never ceased being a husband and father, and therefore had responsibility towards the baby.

I think the story is about the Alter Rebbe, who does not have the responsibility to care for the baby, demonstrating the value of universal compassion by stopping his contemplation to tend to it, not about the Rabbi Dov Ber's familial obligations.

@Obie2.0 It is not there is no compassion by Ven Saṅgāmaji. He would have taken care of the baby if the mother had walked away. The Buddha too would have intervened if necessary. The point is there is a price to pay for everything. What is the cost of compassion? To say there is no cost is delusional. It is only when we'd carefully considered and tested various aspects of an issue then can we adopt the right approach at the appropriate time and place in accordance with our intended goals.

To practise deep concentration, normally it is advised to find a place that is secluded and away from human activities. A household life is just not conducive for it. Likewise, taking care of a baby is a full-time commitment, it is irresponsible to be half-hearted about it. Wanting it all is as good as not knowing what one is getting into.

There's a "Zen story" titled, Is That So?

The Zen master Hakuin was praised by his neighbors as one living a
pure life.
A beautiful Japanese girl whose parents owned a food store lived near
him. Suddenly, without any warning, her parents discovered she was
with child.
This made her parents angry. She would not confess who the man was,
but after much harassment at last named Hakuin.
In great anger the parent went to the master. "Is that so?" was all he
would say.
After the child was born it was brought to Hakuin. By this time he had
lost his reputation, which did not trouble him, but he took very good
care of the child. He obtained milk from his neighbors and everything
else he needed.
A year later the girl-mother could stand it no longer. She told her
parents the truth – the real father of the child was a young man who
worked in the fishmarket.
The mother and father of the girl at once went to Hakuin to ask
forgiveness, to apologize at length, and to get the child back.
Hakuin was willing. In yielding the child, all he said was: "Is that
so?"

The story or plot is similar but, as this is a Zen story, perhaps I should not explain its message.

If that was Hakuin Ekaku, he was the one who said that "By Kannon Bosatsu is meant the contemplation of sounds, and that is what I mean by the sound of the single hand," in reference to Avalokiteśvara. That idea of hearing a faint sound as an analogy for universal compassion actually seems to have a lot of resonance with the Jewish story.

That's a good teaching. Liberation from suffering is the ultimate goal of Buddhism, and religion in general, but it might as well be a pipe dream, when there's something right in front of you that needs to be addressed, and you can do something about. Compassion is a core value, and in the Mahayana branch there's the bodhisattva ideal and vow, where you make it your intention to get Enlightened for the sake of leading others to it, even going as far as forestalling your own, til all other beings are there. The latter seems unrealistic, and teachers have pointed out that you can't save someone from drowning til you get yourself to safety. But the compassion is cultivated, and just the intention makes a noticeable difference in your quality of mind.
But there's a story where two Zen monks and a woman come to a river, and the older monk picks up the woman and carries her across. The other monk was shocked and appalled that he'd even touched a woman, and the older one said, "I put her down at the other side of the river. Why are you still carrying her?" It's a little like when Jesus asks the rhetorical question, "Is it permitted to do good, or to do evil, on the Sabbath." Some things are more important, and situations call for different responses. It's the principle or spirit of the law that matters, and is the reason a rule is made in the first place. How does someone call themselves "religious" if they're more concerned with abstract concepts than the immanent suffering of those around them. In Buddhism silabbata paramasa means clinging to rules and rituals for their own sake, and it's said to be a hindrance to one's development. It's even said that the Buddha's teachings are like a raft, which you don't need anymore when you get to the other shore (Enlightenment).
Another thing monks teach is to pay attention to your surroundings when it's called for, and not be so lost in contemplation, or mindfulness of the body, etc. that you're oblivious to danger, and I think that would apply to sila/morality as well.
But with the baby, it wasn't that the younger rabbi was ignoring him, he just couldn't hear. And then you'd have to ask whether he could have even avoided becoming so engrossed in study, or was it out of his control. I knew a kid for 30 years, who couldn't hear his own name being yelled at him repeatedly, if he was lost in thought or watching TV, and it wasn't that he was ignoring you on purpose.
It's said that in the rarefied meditative absorption known as the jhana states, the senses and body drop off and you're not aware of them anymore. But before that happens, concentration on a meditation object can become strong enough that your attention doesn't easily stray from it.

Interesting story… Once I was in an airport waiting to fly somewhere (it was a long time ago, so forgive me for being short on details). Planes were delayed for some reason, and everyone in the airport was simultaneously resigned and cranky. I was just sitting with it, when down the concourse a baby started wailing. Its cries came in long, slow, intermittent waves that actually dropped me into a deeper meditative state.
My point is that 'crying baby' isn't a singular thing, much less a meme. Babies cry to communicate, and cry in different ways for different purposes. Part of the goal of meditation is to find that balanced state were:

Our minds do not react to disturbances so that our thoughts demand engagement with them (trying to force the world around us to conform to our desire for inner stillness: a kind of craving)
Our minds do not reject disturbances to the point of obliviousness (trying to shut down our senses and force out the world: a kind of aversion)

When we meditate, we are working to hold the world around us in a state of not-doing, with the understanding that most things don't need to be dealt with the moment they appear to our minds. But that carries the understanding that some things do need to be dealt with when they appear. If you're meditating and you have to go to the bathroom, you should do that before you ruin your cushion. If you're meditating and a candle falls over, you should pick it up before the temple burns down. Baby cries are less cut-and-dried; some cries need immediate attention and some don't, and if you listen you'll understand which is which.
And besides, there's always the art of compromise. Cross-legged postures make excellent storage spots for babies (and cats, and small dogs) while you continue with your meditation, right?
Stories are good, but the truth is you can always find a different story with a different outcome, and then the problem of understanding will be right back in your lap (like our proverbial baby), where it belongs.

I think this question is not related to Buddhism.
Firstly, Chabad is a recent sectarian 1775 Pale of Settlement phenomena rather than a long representative mainstream Jewish "tradition".
Secondly, the Chabad story is about studying (reading) texts rather than about something similar to Buddhist samadhi (concentration) or Buddhist enlightenment.
An example of the Lord Buddha's samadhi (inner concentration absorption) is the following:

"Now one time, Pukkusa, I was staying at Atuma, and had my abode in a barn there. And at that time there was a heavy rain, with thunder
rolling, lightning flashing, and thunderbolts crashing. And two
farmers who were brothers were killed close to the barn, together with
four oxen, and a great crowd came forth from Atuma to the spot where
they were killed.
"Now at that time, Pukkusa, I had come out of the barn and was walking up and down in thought before the door. And a certain man from
the great crowd approached me, respectfully greeted me, and stood at
one side.
"And I asked him: 'Why, brother, has this great crowd gathered together?' And he answered me: 'Just now, Lord, there was a heavy
rain, with thunder rolling, lightning flashing, and thunderbolts
crashing. And two farmers who were brothers were killed close by,
together with four oxen. It is because of this that the great crowd
has gathered. But where, Lord, were you?'
"'I was here, brother.' 'Yet, Lord, did you not see it?' 'I did not
see it, brother.' 'But the noise, Lord, you surely heard?' 'I did not
hear it, brother.' Then that man asked me: 'Then, Lord, perhaps you
slept?' 'No, brother, I was not sleeping.' 'Then, Lord, you were
conscious?' 'I was, brother.' Then that man said: 'Then, Lord, while
conscious and awake, in the midst of a heavy rain, with thunder
rolling, lightning flashing, and thunderbolts crashing, you neither
saw it nor heard the noise?' And I answered him, saying: 'I did not,
brother.'
"And to that man, Pukkusa, came the thought: 'Marvellous it is, most wonderful indeed it is, the state of calmness wherein abide those
who have gone forth from the world!' And there arose in him great
faith in me, and he respectfully saluted me, and keeping his right
side towards me, he went his way."
DN 16

Or the following is an example of the Buddha's chief disciple; the foremost with wisdom:

On a moonlit night, Ven. Sāriputta — his head newly shaven — was
sitting in the open air, having attained a certain level of
concentration.
And on that occasion two yakkhas who were companions were flying from
north to south on some business or other. They saw Ven. Sāriputta —
his head newly shaven — sitting in the open air. Seeing him, the first
yakkha said to the second, "I'm inspired to give this contemplative a
blow on the head."
Then the first yakkha, ignoring the second yakkha, gave Ven. Sāriputta a blow on the head. And with that blow he might have knocked over an elephant seven or eight cubits tall, or split a great rocky crag. But right there the yakkha — yelling, "I'm burning!" — fell into the Great Hell.
Now, Ven. Moggallāna — with his divine eye, pure and surpassing the human — saw the yakkha give Ven. Sāriputta a blow on the head. Seeing this, he went to Ven. Sāriputta and, on arrival, said to him, "I hope you are well, friend Sāriputta. I hope you are comfortable. I hope you are feeling no pain."
"I am well, friend Moggallāna. I am comfortable. But I do have a slight headache."
"How amazing, friend Sāriputta! How astounding! How great your power & might! Just now a yakkha gave you a blow on the head. So great was that blow that he might have knocked over an elephant seven or eight cubits tall, or split a great rocky crag. But all you say is this: 'I am well, friend Moggallāna. I am comfortable. But I do have a slight headache'!"
The Blessed One — with the divine ear-property, pure and surpassing the human — heard those two great beings conversing in this way. Then, on realizing the significance of that, the Blessed One on that occasion exclaimed:
Whose mind, standing like rock,
doesn't shake,
dispassionate for things that spark passion,
unprovoked by things that spark provocation:
When one's mind is developed like this,
from where can there come to him
suffering & stress?
Ud 4.4

Already there are posts here showing the very opposite Buddhist approach.

When seven year old Rahula was ordained by Buddha,the father of
Sidhartha, a king, was grieved. King had lost Siddhartha and Nanda,
his sons, and Devdatta, his nephew. But now that his grandson had been
taken from him...


a monk by the name of Sanghamaji, who, when seated under a tree, was
visited by his former wife, carrying their infant son. She tried
several times to get his attention, and having failed, left the son at
his feet and went a short distance away, to observe his reaction. The
monk neither reacted, nor said anything to the woman or her child. She
then took back the child and left the scene, while lamenting about her
former husband's lack of feelings for them, saying "the monk doesn't
even care about his son. The Buddha, who witnessed this
supernaturally, praised the monk, saying (I paraphrase here) that he
showed equanimity and is free from attachment, and is therefore a
brahman.


As I understand the Dhamma taught by the Blessed One, it’s not easy,
living at home, to practice the holy life totally perfect, totally
pure, a polished shell

Judaism is a social tribal ideology (similar to Brahmanism) and is very distant from Buddhist enlightenment which is founded upon celibacy, impartial universal love, complete harmlessness & abandoning the household life.
I guess the closest Buddhist sutta to the question is about how monks who practice samadhi (absorption) & enlightenment should not disparage those monks who only study & preach.

Thanks a lot! I do stand behind the relation to Buddhism. As you mentioned, Chabad is a relatively recent sect in Judaism, formed about 250 years ago as part of the larger Chassidic movement. However, the Chassidic movements is just a new form of Jewish Mysticism, which has deep roots in the Kabbalistic movement of the 12th-13th centuries, which itself has deep roots going back to turn of the millennium era (as modern academic scholarship shows). It's not far-fetched to claim that some facets of this Mysticism, like concepts of no-self and absolute reality, are common to both traditions.

I guess there can some commonality between samadhi and study (though maybe not according to your understanding of those words/experiences). My dad, was a Catholic and scholar, I was remembering yesterday his saying to me once, "my work is my salvation". I assumed at the time he meant that in the sense of its being an object of focus.

Jhana has at most only six factors: non-verbal noting; non-verbal exploring (of) rapture, happiness, ekaggata. equanimity. nothing else

Kabbalistic is a 12th century movement, obviously influenced or copied from Islamic Sufi mysticism which was obviously influenced or copied from Buddhism (when Islam spread to Persia). There is no such thing as Biblical Jewish mysticism. Judaism is merely a tribal social religion about tribal law, that is all. "Judah" is a tribe or family name. "Judah" is self. The word 'Buddha' means "awakened". Buddha is not a family name. Buddhism is not "Gotama-ism". The Buddha taught a person's former "name & clan" is erased when joining the Buddha's community.

its unlikely Chabad focuses upon not-self (anatta). When there is the perception of not-self, per the Buddhist Pali Suttas, the notions of name & clan (nama-gotta), aka, "tribe", fall away. Refer to AN 8:19 https://suttacentral.net/an8.19/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=main&notes=none&highlight=false&script=latin

When they reach the ocean, all the great rivers—that is, the Ganges, Yamunā, Aciravatī, Sarabhū, and Mahī—lose their names and clans and are simply considered ‘the ocean’. In the same way, when they go forth from the lay life to homelessness, all four classes—aristocrats, brahmins, peasants, and menials—lose their former names and clans and are simply considered ‘Sakyan ascetics’. AN 8:19

Wikipedia says: "But above all, Jewish Kabbalah is a set of sacred and magical teachings meant to explain the relationship between the unchanging, eternal God—the mysterious Ein Sof (אֵין סוֹף‎, 'The Infinite')  —and the mortal, finite universe (God's creation)". In Buddhism, such an ideology is an example of ETERNALISM. ETERNALISM is a wrong view in Buddhism. As i suggested in my answer, Judaism has similarities to Brahmanism, which became Hinduism (which have the ideology of Eternal Soul/Self and Eternal Brahman/God).

Wikipedia says Kabbalah emerges in Spain. This is when Spain was ruled by Muslims. Keep in mind, the great "Golden Ages" of Jewish Civilisation occurred when Jews lived in the Muslim Empires. For example Maimonides was born & lived in the Muslim world and some of his innovations resembled Islam. Islam & Judaism are very close traditions. For example, the Kingdom of Israel was dissolved in 720BC and those Israelites that returned became Samaritans. Samaria later converted to Islam. For example I guess many present day Gazans are descended from former Hebrews. Chabad is European.

That bit about "impartial universal love" seems to be more or less what the Chabad story advocates, even if it does not focus on abandoning household life or celibacy. I'm not sure that the traditions are as far apart as you seem to claim. In point of fact, the top comment suggests that Chabad is based on Kabbalah, which you yourself connect to Buddhism via Sufi Muslims influenced by Persian thought.

There were no doubt external influences, but at its core, Jewish Mysticism precedes many traditions you mentioned (although there's indeed no doubt that it came to its full form on 12th-13th centuries), with ancient traditions like the Merkabah mysticism and the Hekhalot literature, and others.
